# Preparing data for linear mixed effects model

Tags: lme4-nlme

I want to fit my linear mixed effects model to test the impact of an ecological restoration project. I have a single (impact) site and (multiple) control sites and multiple before/after years data set. I would want to use the lme4 package for my analysis. However, my first obstacle is the structure of my data shown below"

```
 Period Year Impact Control1 Control2 Control3 Control4 Control5
 Before 2000  0.326    0.410    0.342    0.376    0.330    0.400
 Before 2001  0.294    0.354    0.328    0.351    0.300    0.354
 Before 2002  0.234    0.298    0.288    0.261    0.234    0.304
 Before 2003  0.210    0.153    0.160    0.170    0.129    0.167
 Before 2004  0.248    0.327    0.296    0.328    0.257    0.320
 Before 2005  0.251    0.310    0.292    0.348    0.254    0.306
 Before 2006  0.232    0.275    0.263    0.279    0.225    0.265
 Before 2007  0.231    0.273    0.260    0.282    0.224    0.265
  After 2008  0.225    0.285    0.253    0.311    0.229    0.290
  After 2009  0.197    0.224    0.212    0.251    0.186    0.217
  After 2010  0.212    0.242    0.216    0.276    0.208    0.228
```

Is this how the data should be structured? 
I am also not sure if this is the proper way to fit the model and obtain the p-value.

```
library(lmerTest)    
model2 = lmer(Impact ~ Control1 + Control2 + Control3 + Control4 + Control5 +
              (1|Period), data = d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert your data from the current format (i.e., wide format) to long format, so that it looks like this:

```
Period  Year  SiteClass  Outcome 
Before  2000  Impact       0.326    
Before  2000  Control1     0.410    
Before  2000  Control2     0.342    
Before  2000  Control3     0.376   
Before  2000  Control4     0.330    
Before  2000  Control5     0.400 
etc.
```

where `SiteClass` denotes the classification of sites as either `Impact` or `Control` and `Outcome` is whatever response variable you are measuring.

Then you could perhaps start by trying to fit a model along these lines:

```
require(lme4)
require(lmerTest)

result.lmer <- lmer(Outcome ~ Period + SiteClass + Period:SiteClass +
                   (1|YearF) + (1|Site), 
                   data=long_format_data)

anova(result.lmer, ddf="Kenward-Roger")
```

where `YearF` is obtained by converting Year from numeric to a factor:

```
long_format_data$YearF <- as.factor(long_format_data$Year)
```

and Site would be a factor which you need to define in long_format_data such that it keeps track of your sites. For example,  Site = "1" for Impact, Site = "2" for Control1, ..., Site = "6" for Control 5.

The long_format_data you would need to fit the above model would look something like this:

```
Period  Year  SiteClass  Outcome  YearF  Site
Before  2000  Impact       0.326  2000     1
Before  2000  Control1     0.410  2000     2 
Before  2000  Control2     0.342  2000     3
Before  2000  Control3     0.376  2000     4  
Before  2000  Control4     0.330  2000     5 
Before  2000  Control5     0.400  2000     6
etc.
```

The above model formulation reflects the fact that the years (`YearF`) and sites (`Site`) included in the study are representative of a larger set of years and sites to which you may wish to generalize your findings.  In the model, you can therefore include `YearF` and `Site` as random (partially crossed?) grouping factors via the syntax (`1|YearF`) + (`1|Site`). For each `YearF` by Site combination, you have two values of the Outcome variable - one before the impact and one after the impact.

Please see CHAPTER 12. ANALYSIS OF BACI EXPERIMENTS of this document for further details: http://people.stat.sfu.ca/~cschwarz/Stat-650/Notes/PDFbigbook-R/PDFbigbook-R.pdf.

Comment: @Archford: Great!  The document I linked to at the end of the post will give you more insights into how to proceed with your analysis.

Comment: @Stefan: Thank you for editing the answer I provided - it's really nice of you! 

Answer (score 1):

Code is needed for Site: 1= Impact, 2=Control1, 3=Control2, 4=Control3, 5=Control4, 6=Control5. Then covert the data into following style:

```
       Period  Year   Site    Y
       Before  2000    1    0.326
       Before  2000    2    0.410
       Before  2000    3    0.342
       Before  2000    4    0.376 
       Before  2000    5    0.330
       Before  2000    6    0.400
       Before  2001    1    0.294  
       Before  2002    2    0.354
        ...     ...    ...    ...
```

Model will be Y ~ Site + Period + Year + random effects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In this case, what would you recommend to be my random effects?

Comment: I did not see that you need random effects. Especially, in your original code, you used (1|period), but I did not find the period in your data.